# Creating an array of objects with derived classes

Tags: java, arrays, object, derived-class, derived

I am attempting to create two players in the program I am writing. The issue is that there are three types of players that can be created but in order to reference them later I want them named as player one and player two. The three classes: "Human", "Computer", and "Karen" are derived classes of "Player". I am wondering how to create an array Player that I can then put player1 and player2 objects in. Is this possible to do?

```
int playerType = 0;
int highestScore = 0;
Player[] player = new Player[2]; // This is the array of type Player, the master class

Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);

for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    System.out.println ("Choose a type of player:");
    System.out.println ("1: Human");
    System.out.println ("2: Computer (Threshold = 20)");
    System.out.println ("3. Computer (Custom)");
    System.out.print ("? : ");

    playerType = Integer.valueOf(userInput.nextLine()); // gets input choice from user


  switch (playerType)
    {
      case 1:
        Human player[i] = new Human();
      case 2:
        Computer player[i] = new Computer();
      case 3:
        Karen player[i] = new Karen();
    }

}
```

There is another method I tried, using an if statement to make an object playerOne or playerTwo based on what iteration of the for loop we were on (i). Unfortunately it doesn't look like java will compile it because there are multiple declarations of the same variable, even though only one of the declarations should run.

```
if(playerNumber == 1){
  switch (playerType)
    {
      case 1:
        Human playerOne = new Human();
      case 2:
        Computer playerOne = new Computer();
      case 3:
        Karen playerOne = new Karen();
    }
}

if(playerNumber == 2){
  switch (playerType)
    {
      case 1:
        Human playerTwo = new Human();
      case 2:
        Computer playerTwo = new Computer();
      case 3:
        Karen playerTwo = new Karen();
    }
}
```

The solution suggested by OldProgrammer is below, it worked perfectly. However, I am now having an issue calling methods of: Human, Computer, and Karen. I get the following error when trying to execute:

```
System.out.println(player[i].getName() + ", your turn");
```

**Error Msg:**

```
Main.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println(player[i].getName() + ", your turn");
                                ^
symbol:   method getName()
location: class Player
1 error
```

The method in each class looks like this:

```
public class Karen extends Player {
private String playerName = "Karen";

public String getName(){
  return playerName;
}
```

}

Comment: Change "Human player[i] = new Human();" to "player[i] = new Human();", etc.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Okay that worked well. Now I am having issues though calling methods from the individual classes. For instance if I do player[i].getName() which should call that method in: Human, Computer, or Karen. However I get the following error:
error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(player[i].getName() + ", your turn");
                                    ^

Comment: @OldProgrammer I've added what I am referring to in the question. It should be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to OldProgrammer:

> Change "Human player[i] = new Human();" to "player[i] = new Human();", etc.

Understanding how derived classes is really important and I'm glad this is how it works. Thank you very much and I hope this might help someone in the future. Here is my updated code for full clarification:

```
int highestScore = 0;
Player[] player = new Player[2]; 

Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    System.out.println ("Choose a type of player:");
    System.out.println ("1: Human");
    System.out.println ("2: Computer (Threshold = 20)");
    System.out.println ("3. Computer (Custom)");
    System.out.print ("? : ");

    playerType = Integer.valueOf(userInput.nextLine());

  switch (playerType)
    {
      case 1:
        player[i] = new Human();
      case 2:
        player[i] = new Computer();
      case 3:
        player[i] = new Karen();
    }

}
```